# Get number of users that logged in last month by laravel

Tags: php, datetime, laravel, eloquent

Every user log in ,I save log in date by:

```
if(Auth::check()){
      $user = Auth::user();
      $user->last_login_at = date('Y-m-d H:i:s');
      $user->save();
}
```

Now, how can I get number of users that logged in last month?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As I see you have some **Auth** stuff, you surely have the **User** model somewhere in your app. You can fetch the users you want using the below code (untested but should work for you):

```php
//users logged during a period of month ago from now
User::where('last_login_at', '>=', new DateTime('-1 months'))->get(); 

//users logged from the beggining of current callendar month
User::where('last_login_at', '>', new DateTime('last day of previous month'))->get();
```

**EDIT:**
The "-1 months" or "last day of previous month" are the so called DateTime Relative Formats - check the below documentation for futher details and interesting ideas on date calculations.

http://www.php.net/manual/en/datetime.formats.relative.php

Comment: What do you mean dynamic ? it already is dynamic, as it is a relative operator - it bases on the idea of "now" as the base date for calculations. Check my edit for a link to the DateTime documentation, where you will find all the details on how to manipulate it.